# insert to database checked row in datagridview in c# using ado.net

Tags: c#, sql-server, checkbox, datagridview, ado.net

Code:

```
int i = 0;
List<int> ChkedRow = new List<int>();
for (i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == "yes")
    {
        ChkedRow.Add(i);
    }
}

if (ChkedRow.Count == 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Select one checkbox");
    return;
}

foreach (int j in ChkedRow)
{
    try
    {
        Query = "Insert into dbo.tbl_Class(Class_Name,Category,Description,Item) values ('" + txtname.Text + "','" + cbo_cat.Text + "','" + txtdesc.Text + "','" + dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[1].Value.ToString() + "')";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, con);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
MessageBox.Show("Records successfully inserted");
```

I want to save in sql the row that i selected in my datagridview but I'm having a **error in this line** `"if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == "yes")"` . and I don't know why. can you please help me with this? or suggest another code or another approach? Please help.

Comment: What error you have experience in that line?

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == "yes" is yes is save in your database or not?

Comment: if yes. it will going to save.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure what error you are getting but you will definitely get in IndexOutOfRange exception or something similar because of the way you are iterating through the rows here...

```
for (i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
```

`RowCount` returns the total amount of rows, however, you are accessing a zero-based index which will throw the above mentioned xception as soon as you hit the last iteration. So, you have to change the evaluation expression in the for loop to exclude the last iteration as below...

```
for (i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
```

#### Update

Based on your comment, since you're getting a `NullReferenceException`, you should make sure that the  value of the cell has been set to something else than null as below...

```
var row = dataGridView1.Rows[i];
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Cells[0].Value) && row.Cells[0].Value.ToString() == "yes")
{
    ChkedRow.Add(i);
}
```

also try using `dataGridView1.Rows.Count` instead of the `RowCount` property

Comment: I already try it but doesn't include my last row that i checked. example sir. I select a,b and c. but it will going to save only a and b.

Comment: @Novice not sure what you mean, the last row index will always be `dataGridView1.RowCount -1`, for that reason you must stop the iteration when `i == dataGridView1.RowCount -1`...remember that the index is zero-based

Comment: Example sir. I have A in row0, B in row1 and C in row2. i select them all. When I am saving them to database only A in row0 and B in Row1 will save. and  I really dont have any idea why.

Comment: @Novice does the value of cell C (row2) equals "yes"? You are saving only the cells whose value = "yes!!! If the value is not equal to "yes" it will NOT be saved

Comment: Yes sir. the value is Yes. but it doesn't include.

Comment: @Novice are you setting `RowCount` manually by any chance? Try using `dataGridView.Rows.Count` instead and see what happens

Comment: where do i going to put it??

Comment: @Novice look there's nothing wrong with the code you've provided. You should debug your application and provide more information if you want more help

Comment: i cant attached picture so that you can understand what i mean. do you have YM?

Comment: i already fixed it sir. instead of datagridview i used CheckListView.

Answer (score 0):

have u tried with columnname instead of int index?

```
if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["ColumnName"].Value.ToString() == "yes")
            {
                ChkedRow.Add(i);
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

try this,

```
foreach (GridViewRow grdRow in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
int count=0;
chk = (CheckBox)grdRow.FindControl("check box name");
if (chk != null && chk.Checked == true)
{ 
    //write code for insesrt
    count++;
}
}

if(count==0)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Select one checkbox");
}
```

Comment: GridViewRow was not found sir.

Comment: @Banana `GridViewRow` is not part of the Windows Forms control suite, it is part of the ASP.NET Web Forms framework